# How to send HTTP Headers to an included page in php?

Tags: php, include, http-headers

I need to include some URL in php.. 
I used the following code:

```
<? include 'http://my_server.com/some_page.jsp?test=true'; ?>
```

The problem is that, the page `some_page.jsp` act differentially based on the request header`user-agent` that appears not being sent by the above include statement...

So How can I force the browser to send the request headers too to the included page?

Thanks.

Comment: Does that jsp file you are including via url generate php code?

Answer (score 2):

That is a bad pattern to use, if it is on your own server, you should just include it via a relative path (why invoke HTTP) and if it isn't, you are basically handing the keys to your site over to the other domain.

To request another document with a different user agent, try the cURL library.

**Do not continue, for informative purposes only...**

If you *must* run the resulting PHP code (and I strongly advise you don't, and most importantly **why?**) you can then `eval()` the response.

#### Update

You need `allow_url_include` on to include a URL, and it is off by default. If you enable it, you can then set the user agent with the `user_agent` option.

If you are doing this to join a `php` and `jsp` site together, you should try and stick to *only sending data* between them, not code for the other to run over HTTP.

Comment: No, it is not on my own server, it is on a customer server

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but note that he is invoking a .jsp page, not just a php script he can include.  Perhaps this bad pattern is only to glue together a php and java system?

Comment: @Kazar Thanks, I totally glossed over that. My bad. The `.jsp` file can still output PHP code though :P

Comment: @حمد You better trust your customer :)

Comment: for `allow_url_include`, yes.. but this is not the whole story.. the include stmt above is working but not sending the request headers to the `jsp` page. how do that?

Comment: @حمد See the update, I have provided two methods (change `php.ini`, `ini_set()` or cURL).

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
<? include 'http://my_server.com/some_page.jsp?test=true'; ?>
```

is not going to act as you expected.

Check-out: HttpClient

http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/

There are user manual and example

Answer (score 0):

You can't set all the HTTP headers that are sent, but you can set the user-agent string that is sent like so:

```
<? 

ini_set("user_agent", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
include 'http://my_server.com/some_page.jsp?test=true'; 

?>
```

The user_agent value is NULL by default, which is why you don't currently see anything being sent.

That should do the trick.  Note that if the .jsp file returns html content rather than php, you should use `readfile`, not `include`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly advise you not to use your code in a live environment, ever. Instead, use [Client-URL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

For example, you can do it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
// the website
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/path/to/webpage');
// this line sets up curl so the website contents will be returned
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// the user agent, for example firefox
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

If you absolutely need to execute the code afterwards, then you can perform a lot of checking and `eval()` it, but only if you have to. A better approach would be some kind of dictionary.